# How to load not amd modules with require.js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I am using backbone and require.js for uploading some lib files with success.

```
    <script data-main="js/config" src="js/libs/require.js"></script>
```

I am trying to load a simple modal window plugin http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/25/nifty-modal-window-effects/ it seems to work but when I am trying to refer to the object it's undefined. 
The plug-in is not an AMD module rather a simple javascript module.

```
var ModalEffects = (function() { .......
......... function init() {...}
.........
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a shim configuration for non amd compliant modules:

```
require.config({
   shim: {
      'modalEffects': {  exports: 'modalEffects' }
   },

   paths: {
       'modalEffects': '/path_to_the_plugin_file'
   }
});
```

you can add this to the config.js file

Alternatively you can add the following line to the config.js file:

```
define('modalEffects', function() { return ModalEffects });
```

In the latter case you would need to include the script manually into the page

Comment: hmm. is it possible to refer to modaleffects before the alias is set in paths?

Comment: Could you give some more information. Why would you want to refer to moddalEffects before the alias is set in paths?